# How can I extract minute from time in BigQuery?

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

How can I extract hour from timestamp/time column in BigQuery?

Timestamp Column sample value: 4/1/2020 12:57:55

Time Column sample value: 12:57:55

I have tried using

```
    EXTRACT(minute from Timestamp)
    split(Time,'')[ordinal(1)]
```

`split` returns only one value and does not solve my concern.
Regular SQL extract does not work.

Comment: Please explain what "not working" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I could understand, your datetime column is formatted as string. So you need to parse it first to datetime.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(minute from PARSE_DATETIME('%e/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', '4/1/2020 12:57:55'))
```

For time column, you can use this one:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(minute from CAST('12:57:55' AS time))
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract the hour from the scalar column, you can use:

```
EXTRACT(hour FROM Timestamp)
```

`EXTRACT()` works for both `TIMESTAMP`s and `TIME`s.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I need the minute value from the timestamp/time.
I have corrected my question.